# how to tap into mappingcontext.processAnonType

Tags: breeze

we use breezejs to get both entities and non entities from the server... for the non entities we would like to mess with the returned objects, specifically we want to set their prototype... after stepping through the breeze code it seems like the perfect spot to do this would be in the function below of the MappingContext... here we have access to "result" which is the object breeze returns to the client and we also have access to the "$type" property of "node". With this information on hand we could find a constructor function by parsing $type and update result with it so that result will look like an instance of the constructor function found... are there any interception points that could help me? my problem is that when the objects are handed over by breeze, i don't have access to the "node.$type" property which i need in order to find the constructor function... thank you

```
function processAnonType(mc, node) {
        // node is guaranteed to be an object by this point, i.e. not a scalar          
        var keyFn = mc.metadataStore.namingConvention.serverPropertyNameToClient;
        var result = {};

        __objectForEach(node, function (key, value) {
            var newKey = keyFn(key);
            var nodeContext = { nodeType: "anonProp", propertyName: newKey };
            visitNode(value, mc, nodeContext, result, newKey);
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you can do what you need by using a custom *jsonResultsAdapter*. See: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/jsonresultsadapters

In the visitNode method you can either modify the incoming 'node' object or create a new one ( via a 'node' property on the returned hash). If the node is NOT an entity then whatever you return will be passed thru without modification to your client.

Comment: thank you for the response. but i don't understand how a custom jsonresultsadapter is going to help me. according to the link you sent, jsonresultsadapter has two methods i would potentially override, extractresults and visitnode. when looking into these two methods and their current implementation i don't see where in either of these my logic would fit it if were to create a custom one. isn't visitnode meant to return info on how to process the node?

Comment: You can modify the incoming node in visitNode ( more detail added to the answer above).

Comment: hi jay. i'm just now getting back to implementing. sorry ahead of time for being such a hard head but i just don't get how through jra.visitnode i can achieve what i want. for starters the document on jra says at the very bottom that the objects returned by breeze are NEVER the same as the incoming json objects. and sure enough stepping through the breeze code, this is indeed the case. but above you say "If the node is NOT an entity then whatever you return will be passed thru without modification to your client". i'm totally confused.

Comment: to continue from where i left off above... stepping through the code i don't see any way i can through jra.visitnode set the prototype of the object that breeze ultimately returns as a result of processing a node of type "anonType". if you look at the function "processAnonType" I posted above, i basically need to set the prototype of the "results" variable somehow. again, i just don't see how to accomplish this through jra.visitNode as you advised.

Comment: sorry these comments are too short... as i was saying... I understand that in visitnode i can create a new node and return that node as part of the meta hash, BUT for nodes of type "entitytype" or "anontype", even if i return a new node with the prototype set, breeze is still going to create a new object and copy the properties over, and i don't think it copies the prototype. do you understand what i am saying or am i not making any sense? thanks again